# I can't seem to get my footer to be at the bottom of the page when combining with my other elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make my footer stay at the bottom of the page and have been going through some of the youtube tutorials. For some strange reason, they do work when I tried the footer by itself but when combining with my other elements, I seem to have some problems with not only getting the footer to be at the bottom of the page but I can't also get my display: inline-block to work well....

I have been trying to follow this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qlCIXXhSX6Y&t=191s and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FGBsGqn7ac8&lc=z22eihehdzrajv13qacdp4334oiod53pnruzdum2ru1w03c010c.1541183153454115

I have a separate footer.php and have included into my index.php file.... Should I have my div ids in the index.php page or footer.php?

This is my footer code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-/rXc/GQVaYpyDdyxK+ecHPVYJSN9bmVFBvjA/9eOB+pb3F2w2N6fc5qB9Ew5yIns" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


    </head>
    <body>

    <section class="content">

    <footer>

      <div class="main-footer">
       <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
             <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="footer-bg">
                   <div class="footer-address">
                       <h1>Learn Classical Music at <span>PianoCourse101</span></h1>
                       <h2>Location: Australia, Melbourne</h2>
                   </div>
                   <div class="footer-email-phone">
                      <ul>
                         <li><a href="tel:+1234567890"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+123-456-7890</a></li>
                         <li><a href="mailto:info@PianoCourse101.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>info@pianocourse101.com</a></li>
                      </ul>
                   </div>

                      <div class="footer-social-icons">
                         <ul>
                             <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                             <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                             <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                             <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                             <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                         </ul>
                      </div>
                </div>
             </div>

            <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="footer-menu">
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">More Information</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>

          <div class="footer-strip">
              <div class="container">
                 <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                       <div class="footer-text">
                           <p>2018 @ All Rights</p>
                       </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
          </div>


    </footer>

    </section>
    </body>
    </html>

This is my index.php page

 <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
     <title>PianoCourse101</title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Aldrich|Mr+Dafoe" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity=">sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Lobster" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes|Lobster|Monoton|Orbitron" rel="stylesheet">

   </head>
   <body>



   <!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8">
  <link
  rel="stylesheet"
  href = "style.css"
  media="screen,projection,tv"
>

<link 
rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.3.1/css/all.css" 
integrity="sha384-mzrmE5qonljUremFsqc01SB46JvROS7bZs3IO2EmfFsd15uHvIt+Y8vEf7N7fWAU" 
crossorigin="anonymous">

<link
rel="stylesheet"
href = "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico"
>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Welcome to PianoCourse101</title>

<div id="container">
    <div id="main">
  <header>
<div class="header2_welcome">
<h1>Welcome to PianoCourse101</h1>
</div>
</header>


<section class="content">



     <div class="crotchet">
<p>&#x1D15F</p>
</div>
<div class="minim">
<p>&#x1D15E</p>
</div>
<div class="quaver">
<p>&#x1D160</p>
</div>

     <img class="pc101" src="includes/pictures/pc101.gif" alt="pianocourse101/">
    <div class="music"><i class="fas fa-music fa-8x"></i></div>

    <div class="sharp"><p>&#9839</p></div>
    <div class="natural"><p>&#9838</p></div>
    <div class="flat"><p>&#9837</p></div>



<article>

      <div class="first">
       <h2>At PianoCourse101, your child can now learn how to play Classical music right from the comfort of your own home! We understand that as a busy mum, you might not have the time to take your child for piano lessons and also, it is a daunting process to find a good quality teacher. Put all of those thoughts aside because PianoCourse101 offers a complete course from the beginning to the advanced levels. It is based on "The Bastien Piano Basics Series" for children and for a limited time, students can watch the Primer Level lessons for <span class="first_free">free!</span> If you would like to continue your lessons beyond Primer Level, you can opt to purchase our Level 1, Level 2, or Level 3 course.<br></br>Currently, the lessons are aimed primarily for children but there will be lessons for adults in the near future. We would appreciate if you could donate to our website if you are enjoying your learning experience with us. This will assist us in maintaining our website and to be able to upload more videos.<br></br> Mr Lee has over ten years of piano teaching experience and also has completed an educational degree and obtained a 4th year in psychology degree. We understand that learning the piano can be boring and hence, we are trying our best to make piano learning a fun and interactive experience for you and your child.<br></br>PianoCourse101 is located in Australia, Melbourne and all fees are in the AUD currency. Student will receive an invoice upon the completion of purchasing a course.</h2>
     </div>
</article>

    <div class="form">
    <form class="signup-form" action="newsletters.php" method="POST">
      <div class="newsletters">
       <label>Enter your E-mail Address</label>
     </div>
       <br></br>
       <div class="index_form"><center><input type="text" name='email' placeholder="Enter E-mail Address"></center>
       <br></br>
       <center><button type="submit" name="submit">Subscribe to PianoCourse101!</button></center>
       <br></br>
    </div>
    </form>
    </div>


    <img class="snoopy" src="includes/pictures/snoopy.jpg" alt="snoopy playing the piano" />



   <div class="services_heading">Services</div>
      <div class="services">
         <div class="service1">
           <h1>Level 1</h1>
           <a href="signup.php"><p id="piano">&#127929</p></a>
           <p>Purchase the Level 1 Subscriptionplan!<br>Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!<br>Monthly fee: $100<br>Yearly fee: $800</p>
          </div>

            <div class="service1">
             <h1>Level 2</h1>
            <a href="signup.php"><p id="violin">&#127931</p></a>
            <p>Purchase the Level 2 Subscriptionplan!<br>Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!<br>Monthly fee: $150<br>Yearly fee: $1300</p>

          </div>
          <div class="service1">
            <h1>Level 3</h1>
            <a href="signup.php"><p id="sax">&#127927</p></a>
            <p>Purchase the Level 3 Subscriptionplan!<br>Learn how to play the piano right from the comfort of your own home!<br>Monthly fee: $200<br>Yearly fee: $1800</p>
         </div>
      </div>


<span class="index_views">There are <span class="views"><?php echo "&nbsp",htmlspecialchars($views); ?></span><?php echo "&nbsp"; ?>visitors who have visited this page!</span>

 </section>

<footer id="footer">

<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>

</footer>
</div>
</div>         
</body>
</html>
```

This is my css for my footer:

```
.main-footer {

   width: 100%;

   height: auto;
   background-image: url(includes/pictures/piano.jpg);
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   -ms-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-attachment: scroll;
   background-position: center;
   padding: 20px 0px;
}

.footer-bg {

  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border: 4px solid #ff6a00;
}

.footer-address {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top:5px;
}

.footer-address h1 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.footer-address h1 span {
  color: #ff6a00;
}

.footer-address h2 {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

.footer-email-phone {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
   margin: auto;
   margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer-email-phone ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;

}

.footer-email-phone ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-email-phone ul li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #333;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.footer-email-phone ul li a i {
  color: #ff6a00;
  padding-right: 5px;
}

.footer-email-phone ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff6a00;
}

.footer-email-phone ul li a:hover i {
  color: #333;
}

.footer-social-icons {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;

}

.footer-social-icons ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-right: 10px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(255,106,0,1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(255,106,0,1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(255,106,0,1);
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li a {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #ff6a00;
  line-height: 30px;
  display: block;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(1):hover {
  background: #3b5999;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(2):hover {
  background: #55acee;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(3):hover {
  background: #dd4b39;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(4):hover {
  background: #cd201f;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(5):hover {
  background: #0077b5;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(1):hover a{
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(2):hover a{
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(3):hover a{
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(4):hover a{
  color: #fff;
}

.footer-social-icons ul li:nth-child(5):hover a{
 color: #fff;
}

.footer-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.footer-menu ul {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}


.footer-menu ul li a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: left;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;

}

.footer-menu ul li:after {
  content: "|";
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 8px;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

.footer-menu ul li:nth-child(3):after {
  content: "";
}

.footer-menu ul li a:hover {
  color: #ff6a00;
}

.footer-strip {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer-text {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.footer-text p {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footer-text p a {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.footer-text p a:hover {
  color: #ff6a00;
}




 [enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: you can use flexbox to put footer at the bottom

Comment: my apologies but I have roughly worked out part of the problem.... My footer doesn't look right and it has something to do with my navigation menu...

Comment: I tried flexbox as well but it does work on its own... I am not sure if it is my navigation menu that is playing up

Comment: for pictures, should I use a div class or img class? When I used a div class, my footer doesn't stay at the bottom

Comment: I have been following another tutorial and for some reason, I managed to get it to work by using position fixed.. Why do some tutorials recommend to use position absolute instead?

Answer (score 0):

all the html you need for your footer include is:

```
<div class="main-footer">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="footer-bg">
               <div class="footer-address">
                   <h1>Learn Classical Music at <span>PianoCourse101</span></h1>
                   <h2>Location: Australia, Melbourne</h2>
               </div>
               <div class="footer-email-phone">
                  <ul>
                     <li><a href="tel:+1234567890"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i>+123-456-7890</a></li>
                     <li><a href="mailto:info@PianoCourse101.com"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>info@pianocourse101.com</a></li>
                  </ul>
               </div>

                  <div class="footer-social-icons">
                     <ul>
                         <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                         <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fab fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </div>
            </div>
         </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
           <div class="footer-menu">
              <ul>
                 <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">More Information</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
              </ul>
           </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

      <div class="footer-strip">
          <div class="container">
             <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                   <div class="footer-text">
                       <p>2018 @ All Rights</p>
                   </div>
                </div>
             </div>
          </div>
      </div>
```